# docx4j copy image to a new document

Tags: java, docx4j

I am trying to use docx4j to make partial copy of the document to a new document. I am able to copy most part - text, format etc. However, in case of image, I am not able to copy. Doing a deep copy for inline images leave the document incorrectly formatted, and same happens for linked images.

I am attaching code used to make copy

```
word = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File("C:\\Users\\prerak\\Documents\\Projects\\EME\\Exam System\\Documents\\T.docx"));
//newDoc = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
newDoc = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File("C:\\Users\\prerak\\Documents\\Projects\\EME\\Exam System\\Documents\\T.docx"));

MainDocumentPart mdp = word.getMainDocumentPart();
newDoc.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().clear();

Document contents = mdp.getContents();
Body body = contents.getBody();
List<Object> content = body.getContent();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> allQ = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Object> next = null;
for (Object o : content) {

    if (o instanceof P) {
        P p = (P) o;
        List<Object> rs = DocxUtils.getAllElementFromObject(p, R.class);
        for(Object d:rs){
            R tt = (R) d;


            List<Object> ds = tt.getContent();
            for(Object dd:ds){
                System.out.println(dd.getClass().getName());;
            }
        }
        PPr ppr = (PPr) p.getPPr();
        if (ppr != null && ppr.getPStyle() != null) {
            System.out.println("Style: " + ppr.getPStyle().getVal());
            if (ppr.getPStyle().getVal().equals("Heading1")) {
                //System.out.println(o.toString());
            }
        }

    }
    if (o.toString().startsWith("@#")) {
        next = new ArrayList<>();
        allQ.add(next);
    }
    if (next != null) {
        next.add(o);
    }
}
//System.out.println("Total number of questions " + allQ.size());
for (Object o : allQ.get(0)) {
    newDoc.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().add(XmlUtils.deepCopy(o));
}
//System.out.println(DocxUtils.paraToHtml(allQ.get(0)));
newDoc.save(new File("C:\\Users\\prerak\\Documents\\Projects\\EME\\Exam System\\Documents\\newt90.docx"));
```

Do I have to do anything more than making a deep copy?
Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2010/11/merging-word-documents/ regarding referential integrity.

The "brute force" approach is to make a copy of the WordprocessingMLPackage using WordprocessingMLPackage's clone() method, then delete the content you don't want.  That'll leave the image reference and its corresponding part, but also other images etc which you aren't using anymore.  Depending on your circumstances that may or may not be ok.  If it isn't, the commercial MergeDocx code is one solution.

Alternatively, if you know the only references you have are say, images (as opposed to comments, footnotes etc etc), you could handle those specifically in your code.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is I will need to write images from more than one documents to a single target document. I will study the link that you sent and will post after trying out.